# Show more nodes when administering content

Tags: drupal, drupal-5

In my Drupal 5 administrative interface, when I am administering content (Administer -> Content Management -> Content), I can only view 50 nodes per page. I have 350 PAGES of nodes which takes a long time to go through when I have to edit or delete nodes.

I am looking to display more nodes per page.

Comment: or where can I find the node module? :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations is the tool to perform edit, delete & other actions on large number of nodes.